# How should complex numbers be rendered?

Tags: math, notation, complex-numbers

Mathematics naive question:

What is the "canonical" way to represent 14+1i?

```
14+i1
```

or

```
14+i
```

Similarly, is it likely, in the 'real world', that scientific notation is going to creep into a complex number so as to freak out a complex numbers parser? For example,

```
1.2345E+02-1.7002E-09i
```

**Edit:** Finally, is it

```
8.45358210351126e+066i
```

or

```
8.45358210351126e+66i
```

i.e. does one zero file to three digits on the imaginary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems with MATLAB:

```
>> 5+i
ans =
  5.0000 + 1.0000i

>> 5+1i
ans =
   5.0000 + 1.0000i

>> 1.2345E+02-1.7002E-09i
ans =
  1.2345e+002 -1.7002e-009i
```

I think this shows that scientific notation ("`E`") in complex numbers is handled pretty well in the "real world"... to the extent that MATLAB is an influential part of that world =)

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be:

```
14 + i
```

Somehow it's more pleasing to my eyes than 14 + 1i.

Answer (score 0):

I would represent your first example as:

```
14 + 1i
```

And I would certainly expect to see scientific notation in complex numbers. For example, Python happily accepts the following (using `j` as Python requires):

```
>>> 1.2345E+02-1.7002E-09j
(123.45-1.7002e-09j)
```

Answer (score 0):

"14 + 1i" is better than "14+i1", but I'd be more likely to say or write "14 + i".

Also, `1.7002E-09i` (which I haven't seen in Maths, though no doubt it happens in engineering or something) looks a bit ambiguous without a superscripted font (do you mean `1.7002*(10 ** -9)*i` or `1.7002*(10 ** -9*i)`?) and therefore `(1.7002E-09)i` might be better.